# passing custom save argument through a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model with some customizations in the save method.

```
def SomeModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.pop('skip_expensive_processing', False):
            do_expensice_processing()
        return super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically, whenever the save method gets called, I want some expensive process to be executed

But when doing a bunch a saves together (a mass import), I don't want to do the expensive processing on each save. I want to do the expensive process once after all the objects are saved.

In in case of a mass save, the objects are being created through a `ModelForm`. I need to find some way to modify the form so that when the form calls the save method on `SomeModel`, it pases on that `skip_expensive_processing` keyword arg. How do I do this?

I loked through te source of the `ModelForm.save()` method, but it doesn't seem to be caling the model save method in a too straight forward manner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to override the modelform's `save` method. You should just be able to pass `commit=True`, and then the model save won't be called at all.